# Remove line separator from psv file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am getting data from other data sources, and it has few issues. One of them comes from text column. User hit enter on text column, and the export program consider it as end of the row. So that makes the data looks like below.

```
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|$
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Nice$ 
weather"|$
```

Is there any way to remove line separator after Nice then move the weather after Nice?

```
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|$
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Niceweather"|$
```

I am thinking to remove line separator except the one after the pipe, but I don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: is `$` a literal character in your file, or just intended to indicate the end-of-line?

Comment: it is just intended to indicate the end-of-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variant of **39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\"** from [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one)

Instead of joining when the previous line ends in `\`, you want to do so when it *does not* end in `|`. So given

```
$ cat -A file.psv
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|$
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Nice$
weather"|$
```

then

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/|$/!N; s/\n//; ta' file.psv | cat -A
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|$
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Niceweather"|$
```

---

If your file has DOS-style CRLF line endings, i.e.

```
$ cat -A file.psv
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|^M$
"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Nice^M$
weather"|^M$
```

then you can take these into account by changing the command to

```
sed -e :a -e '/|\r$/!N; s/\r\n//; ta' file.psv
```

To edit the file in place, add `-i` (or `-i.bak` for example, to save a backup). To convert the file to Unix line endings as well, add `-e 's/\r$//'`

```
sed -i.bak -e :a -e '/|\r$/!N; s/\r\n//; ta' -e 's/\r$//' file.psv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it worked, but it did not work as I wanted. It is showing up in one line like "abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"hello world"|^M"abc"|"def"|12/28/2019|"Nice^Mweather"|^M$

Comment: @BryanK. that indicates that your files have Windows-style (CRLF) line endings - either convert them to Unix format or try `'/|\r$/!N; s/\r\n//; ta'`

Comment: Thank you it worked!! is there any way to update the original file without the suffix (^M$) instead of having new file?

Comment: @BryanK. please see updated answer

Comment: This is if course not failsafe if the pipe symbol (`|`) can appear in text... (There could be a line break entered after such symbol by user.) So this answers the exact question but is not a production proof answer for many similar cases.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your answer, but sometimes it moves the up some other rows to other rows...

Comment: @EOhm Yes, I just face the issue you mentioned

Comment: @BryanK. to get around that one need to know how escaping is done in the fields (for the `"` quotes), are they doubled or backslashes (or something else)? Also it migth be nice to know wthere the format of the file is fixed (number of lines and field types/quoting) - thougth this is optional and it may in any case better to not take that into account to get a generic solution, maybe slightly more complicated than if You would take such things into account.